# Grep passwords from all web.config files using cygwin

Tags: regex, bash, unix, web-config, grep

I have a bunch of web.config files each possibly containing a connection string to a database like this:-

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myuser;Password=secret" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What I want to do is grep the `User ID=myuser;Password=secret` part out of the line if it exists.

I cannot assume that password is the last property in the connection string, there may be other properties following it. So basically the password will always end with `"` or `;`.

Using cygwin I can search the files like this:-

```
find /cygdrive/c/inetpub/wwwroot/ -iname 'web.config' -printf '%p\0' | xargs -0 grep -i "password="
```

How would i improve the grep part to retrieve only the username and password instead of the entire line ??

I could then pipe it into `sort -u` to get an unique list of usernames and passwords in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep` with the `-P` flag to use Perl's regular-expression engine, and the `-o` flag to return only the matching parts of the input:

```
grep -Po '(User ID|Password)=[^;"]*' web.config
```

This will return the following, considering your sample input:

```
User ID=myuser
Password=secret
```

Give your existing command, it would be something like:

```
find /cygdrive/c/inetpub/wwwroot/ -iname 'web.config' -printf '%p\0' | xargs -0 grep -Poi '(User ID|Password)=[^;"]*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using grep and cut you can do this to extract password:

```
grep -o 'Password=[^;"]*' web.config | cut -d= -f2
```